# How update Image Resource for ImageButton from Main Activity in Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-activity, arduino, dialog

I have Main Activity with activity_main.xml, Dialog with activity_room.xml. I receive data from Arduino via Bluetooth and I want edit ImageButton Image Resource, when receive string "1" or "0". I write receive string to variable, then in Dialog inside if else construction check variable, if 1 ImageResource ON else OFF.

Problem. I can't update image resource when Dialog is open. for update Image Resource i need reopen Dialog

UPDATE.

I can fix my problem with Kludge, many if else, and additional code for arduino.

Dialog Code.

When btnStateOnOff = 1 System on. When btnStateOnOff = 0 System off, and btnStateVent = 0, in adruino if system off, btnStateVent = 2, for not editable imageresource for ImageButton btnStateVentR1. This is my Kludge.

```
    public void DialogR1() {
    dialogRoom1 = new Dialog(this);
    // dialogRoom1.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialogRoom1.setContentView(R.layout.activity_room);
    dialogRoom1.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
    ImageButton btnOnOff = dialogRoom1.findViewById(R.id.btnOnOff);
    ImageButton btnOnOffVent = dialogRoom1.findViewById(R.id.btnOnOffVent);
    ImageButton btnOnOffKlimat = dialogRoom1.findViewById(R.id.btnOnOffKlimat);
    TextView tvDialogR1 = (TextView) dialogRoom1.findViewById(R.id.tvDialog);
    TextView tvTemp = dialogRoom1.findViewById(R.id.tvTemp);
    TextView btnclose = (TextView) dialogRoom1.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
    EditText etWriteTempR1 = dialogRoom1.findViewById(R.id.etWriteTemp);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialogRoom1.getWindow().getAttributes();
    lp.width = MATCH_PARENT;
    lp.height = MATCH_PARENT;
    dialogRoom1.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    dialogRoom1.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);
    tvDialogR1.setText("Room 1");
    dialogRoom1.setCancelable(true);
    tvTemp.setText(temp1);

    if (btnStateOnOff1 == 1) {
        btnOnOff.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
    } else if (btnStateOnOff1 == 0) {
        btnOnOff.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
    }

    if (btnStateVent1 == 1) {
        btnOnOffVent.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
    } else if (btnStateVent1 == 0) {
        btnOnOffVent.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
    }
    else if (btnStateVent1 == 2 ) {
        btnOnOffVent.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
    }
    if (btnStateOnOff1 == 1 && btnStateVent1 == 2){
        btnStateVent1 = 0;
    }

    if (btnStateKlimat1 == 1) {
        btnOnOffKlimat.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
    } else if (btnStateKlimat1 == 0) {
        btnOnOffKlimat.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
    }

    btnOnOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (btnStateOnOff1 == 1) {
                connectedThread.write("onoffr1 0;");
                connectedThread.write("ventr1 0;");
                btnOnOff.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
                btnOnOffVent.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
                btnStateVent1 = 2;
            } else if (btnStateOnOff1 == 0) {
                connectedThread.write("onoffr1 1;");
                btnOnOff.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
                btnStateVent1 = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    btnOnOffVent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (btnStateVent1 == 1) {
                connectedThread.write("ventr1 0;");
                btnOnOffVent.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
            } else if (btnStateVent1 == 0) {
                connectedThread.write("ventr1 1;");
                btnOnOffVent.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
            } else if (btnStateVent1 == 2) {
                btnOnOffVent.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
            }
        }

});
    
    btnOnOffKlimat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()    {
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v){
    if (btnStateKlimat1 == 1) {
        connectedThread.write("klimat1 0;");
        btnOnOffKlimat.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
    } else if (btnStateKlimat1 == 0) {
        connectedThread.write("klimat1 1;");
        btnOnOffKlimat.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
    }
}
});
    btnclose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()    {
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v){
    dialogRoom1.dismiss();
}
});
    etWriteTempR1.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()    {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey (View view,int i, KeyEvent keyEvent){
    if (keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
            (i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
        Log.e("SendText", "temp1 " + etWriteTempR1.getText().toString() + ";");
        connectedThread.write("temp1 " + etWriteTempR1.getText().toString() + ";");
        etWriteTempR1.setText("");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
});
    dialogRoom1.show();
```

Bluetooth Code.

I receive String from arduino, collect bytes to array then parse.

```
        handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case CONNECTING_STATUS:
                    switch (msg.arg1) {
                        case 1:
                            //toolbar.setSubtitle("Connected to " + deviceName);
                            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            btnBluetooth.setEnabled(true);
                            btnSend.setEnabled(true);
                            btnOnOffR1.setEnabled(true);
                            btnOnOffR2.setEnabled(true);
                            btnOnOffR3.setEnabled(true);
                            break;
                        case -1:
                            //toolbar.setSubtitle("Device fails to connect");
                            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            btnBluetooth.setEnabled(true);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                case MESSAGE_READ:
                    arduinoMsg = msg.obj.toString(); // Read message from Arduino
                    receiveArduino = arduinoMsg.split("/");
                    temp1 = receiveArduino[0];
                    temp2 = receiveArduino[1];
                    temp3 = receiveArduino[2];
                    klimat1 = receiveArduino[3];
                    klimat2 = receiveArduino[4];
                    klimat3 = receiveArduino[5];
                    onOffR1 = receiveArduino[6];
                    onOffR2 = receiveArduino[7];
                    onOffR3 = receiveArduino[8];
                    ventr1 = receiveArduino[9];
                    ventr2 = receiveArduino[10];
                    ventr3 = receiveArduino[11];
                    tvTemp1.setText(temp1);
                    tvTemp2.setText(temp2);
                    tvTemp3.setText(temp3);
                    if (onOffR1.equals("1")) {
                        //THIS IS BUTTON PLACE IN ACTIVITY_MAIN.XML, MAIN LAYOUT
                        btnOnOffR1.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
                        btnStateOnOff1 = 1;
                    } else if (onOffR1.equals("0")) {
                        //THIS IS BUTTON PLACE IN ACTIVITY_MAIN.XML, MAIN LAYOUT
                        btnOnOffR1.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
                        btnStateOnOff1 = 0;
                    }
                    if (onOffR2.equals("1")) {
                        //THIS IS BUTTON PLACE IN ACTIVITY_MAIN.XML, MAIN LAYOUT
                        btnOnOffR2.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
                        btnStateOnOff2 = 1;
                    } else if (onOffR2.equals("0")) {
                        //THIS IS BUTTON PLACE IN ACTIVITY_MAIN.XML, MAIN LAYOUT
                        btnOnOffR2.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
                        btnStateOnOff2 = 0;
                    }
                    if (onOffR3.equals("1")) {
                        //THIS IS BUTTON PLACE IN ACTIVITY_MAIN.XML, MAIN LAYOUT
                        btnOnOffR3.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
                        btnStateOnOff3 = 1;
                    } else if (onOffR3.equals("0")) {
                        //THIS IS BUTTON PLACE IN ACTIVITY_MAIN.XML, MAIN LAYOUT
                        btnOnOffR3.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
                        btnStateOnOff3 = 0;
                    }


                    //vent
                    if (ventr1.equals("1")) {
                        //btnOnOffVent.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
                        //THIS IS GOOD SOLUTION FOR ME. THIS BUTTON PLACE IN ACTIVITY_ROOM.XML LAYOUT FOR DIALOG
                        btnStateVent1 = 1;
                    }
                    else if (ventr1.equals("0")) {
                        //btnOnOffVent.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
                        btnStateVent1 = 0;
                    }
                    else if (ventr1.equals("2")){
                        btnStateVent1 = 2;
                    }
                    if (ventr2.equals("1")) {
                        btnStateVent2 = 1;
                    } else if (ventr2.equals("0")) {
                        btnStateVent2 = 0;
                    }
                    if (ventr3.equals("1")) {
                        btnStateVent3 = 1;
                    } else if (ventr3.equals("0")) {
                        btnStateVent3 = 0;
                    }
                    //klimat
                    if (klimat1.equals("1")) {
                        btnStateKlimat1 = 1;
                    } else if (klimat1.equals("0")) {
                        btnStateKlimat1 = 0;
                    }
                    if (klimat2.equals("1")) {
                        btnStateKlimat2 = 1;
                    } else if (klimat2.equals("0")) {
                        btnStateKlimat2 = 0;
                    }
                    if (klimat3.equals("1")) {
                        btnStateKlimat3 = 1;
                    } else if (klimat3.equals("0")) {
                        btnStateKlimat3 = 0;
                    }



                    if (btnStateOnOff1 == 1 && btnStateVent1 == 2){
                        btnStateVent1 = 0;
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I add this code to OnCreate method

```
    dialogRoom1 = new Dialog(this);
    dialogRoom1.setContentView(R.layout.activity_room);
    ImageButton btnOnOffVent = dialogRoom1.findViewById(R.id.btnOnOffVent);
```

Create Public Dialog Method.

All work perfect. HiteshGs thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

can you set image update on UI Thread?

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // changes image here.
    }
});
```

and also if possible share a code line to changes the image.

Comment: I'm not understand what you mean. For edit View in another layout i need call Layout. How can i do that? I edit my question, add code.

Comment: Your Bluetooth code and Dialog in the same activity?

Comment: Yes. In same Main Activity. But different layout

Comment: okay now make dialogRoom1 global(on Activity Scope), 
then whatever component(like btnOnOffR1) you want changes 

adding on define dialogRoom1 and then use it.

cause in your current code I don't found any assignment for btnOnOffR1 in dialogRoom1.